# Creating instances of generic base class

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I am working with the `Dapper.FluentMap` library, and trying to set up auto-registration of my mapping classes. To do that, I need to call `FluentMapConfiguration.AddMap<T>(EntityBase<T>)` for each of the mapping classes.

I can do it like this:

```
public class TypeAMap : EntityMap<TypeA> {}
public class TypeBMap : EntityMap<TypeB> {}
public class TypeCMap : EntityMap<TypeC> {}

public void Register(FluentMapConfiguration configuration)
{
  configuration.AddMap(new TypeAMap());
  configuration.AddMap(new TypeBMap());
  configuration.AddMap(new TypeCMap());
  // I have a hundred of these, you can see where I'm going...
}
```

Obviously a problem in the making when you forget to register a map and wonder why your data isn't loading properly. So on to some reflection to auto-register:

```
public void Register(FluentMapConfiguration configuration)
{
  var maps = GetType().Assembly.GetExportedTypes().Where(t =>
      !t.IsAbstract &&
      !t.IsInterface &&
      t.BaseType is { IsGenericType: true } &&
      t.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(EntityMap<>)
    ).ToArray();

    foreach (var map in maps)
    {
      var baseType = typeof(EntityMap<>);
      var typeArguments = map.BaseType.GetGenericArguments();
      var genericType = baseType.MakeGenericType(typeArguments);
      var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(genericType);

      configuration.AddMap((dynamic) instance);
    }
}
```

but when it gets to the call to `Activator.CreateInstance`, it fails, with a `MissingMethodException`, `Cannot create abstract class`. It looks like it's trying to create an instance of `EntityBase<TypeA>` rather than `TypeAMap`, and since `EntityBase<T>` is an abstract class, I'm getting the error. So how can I construct my instances correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Where` call filters out the types in the assembly and includes only types that are not abstract, not interfaces, and are direct subclasses of `EntityMap<anything>`. So `maps` contains the types `TypeAMap`, `TypeBMap`, `TypeCMap` etc.

Then for each of those, your code gets its base class and tries to instantiate *that* instead. See the annotated code in the for loop:

```
// suppose "map" is typeof(TypeAMap)

var baseType = typeof(EntityMap<>);
// typeArguments would be an array containing typeof(TypeA) only.
var typeArguments = map.BaseType.GetGenericArguments();
// genericType would be typeof(EntityMap<TypeA>)
var genericType = baseType.MakeGenericType(typeArguments);
// now you try to instantiate a EntityMap<TypeA>, and fails, because EntityMap<TypeA> is abstract
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(genericType);
```

Since you want to do the reflection version of `new TypeAMap()`, `new TypeBMap()` etc, and we know that `maps` contain those types that you want to instantiate, you can just do:

```
foreach (var map in maps) 
{
    var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(map);
    configuration.AddMap((dynamic) instance);
}
```

You don't need to care about the generic type parameters for `EntityMap` at all. The dynamic binder will figure that out when it tries to infer the type parameter for `AddMap`.

Comment: This is what happens when you're trying to fix a problem late on a Friday afternoon... many thanks for the well-explained answer!